# Sql Server 2008 R2 Select rows with Dates in multiple columns of each row and ORDER By Dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have ONLY ONE table of `student-wise-activity` in `SqlServer 2008 R2` and IN EACH ROW (of Student-Activity) I have 5 columns of dates `(Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4, Date5)` with corresponding 5 nvarchar columns for `Tasks` in the SAME table for those dates`(Task1, Task2, Task3, Task4, Task5)`.

I need to SELECT By Student-Activity Date-wise Tasks, ORDER BY Asc of Dates.. and Display as follows:

```
Student       Activity      Date       Task    
S-1           Act-1         Date-1     Task-1

...            ....         .....       ....

 S-1          Act-n          Date-x     Task-x
```

......           .......         .....      .......

```
  S-n           Act-1         Date-1        Task-1

......           .......        .......        .......

S-n              Act-n         Date-n       Task-n
```

I am unable to formulate a Select statement for this need. Kindly HELP... Thanks....

Comment: show the relation between both tables to understand more

Comment: @Ajay, Sorry for not mentioning it clearly......  There is ONLY ONE Table...... The Key of the Table is Student-Activity, (2 columns of the Table) Thanks..... Edited my orig post now for more clarity.... thanks...

Comment: what is the meaning of Date-1 , is it actual date with time or only dates. good if you give your some sample data.

Comment: @Ajay,     Date-1,,,,,, , Date5  are columns containing only the Date in the format yyyy-mm-dd e.g. 2015-09-01 for Sep 1, 2015.    Look fwd to your kind help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your table structure like this? (I only use 3 instead of 5 as you mentioned)
[image]

And you want to produce result like this?

[image]

This is the SQL that I use to produce that result (you can adjust the number of date and task)

```
SELECT student, [date], [task]
FROM
(
    SELECT student, [date], [task]
        , date_no = SUBSTRING([dates], LEN([dates]) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE([dates])) + 2, 32)
        , task_no = SUBSTRING([tasks], LEN([tasks]) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE([tasks])) + 2, 32)
    FROM (
        SELECT student, date1, date2, date3, task1, task2, task3 FROM StudentActivity
    ) as st
    UNPIVOT ( [date] FOR [dates] IN (date1, date2, date3) ) AS d
    UNPIVOT ( [task] FOR [tasks] IN (task1, task2, task3) ) AS t
) AS x
WHERE date_no = task_no
```

Comment: Thanks. This works.... But I could not follow HOW!........ I understand Reverse (1234) is 4321 but What is Reverse([Tasks]); also Patindex of Regex; I understand the Regex 'of excluding numbers' but how does it work here?;..... I will appreciate if you can briefly tell me the "the broad Logic of this statement"...  however AS YOUR ANSWER WORKS, I WILL ACCEPT THE SAME.... Thanks a lot... s.FYI, I will not like to use your solution till I understand how it works, in case of any future modification or changes required..so if possible please help......Ratna